# List users in a datagrid, using WCF + RIA with Silverlight 4

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service, datagrid, ria

How to list all registered users from a RIA Service?

I tried to expose they by using a IQueryable (from a Domain Class Service), but got the error "The entity type 'User' is exposed by multiple DomainService types." My first clue is that the user is already exposed, but found nothing in code and there is nothing related to 'User' in 'Data Sources' (from silverlight client project). My guess is the RIA already exposes the User object, but only the authenticated one... how to list all?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During authentication the RIA service will need to fetch `Users` from somewhere so you will need to create another `domain service` to expose `Users`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the attention. Worked fine: created another service called 'MembershipService' that expose a 'UserInfo' type (linked to user).